# Android throws ClassCastException when comparing Short to literal

Tags: android, classcastexception

The project I am working on has the been throwing the following error (names obfuscated)

```
  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Short 
       at com.package.myproject.Object.method(Object.java:656)
```

The problem is the line that is causing the error looks like this.

```
if ( (fileVerMaj.value > 1 || ( fileVerMaj.value == 1 && fileVerMin.value >= 24) ))
```

The variables here are all of the Short type. This code works in when Compiled in Eclipse, but not when compiled in Android Studio. To fix this I have tried the using the Short objects intValue() method and casting the literals to shorts (both the primitve type and the Object). Nothing has changed the behavior.

I need some of Android Studios functionality to compile this project correctly, but I am out of ideas as to whats going on here.

Comment: This is not enough code to clarify anything.

Comment: "I have tried the using the Short objects intValue()" - Should have worked. "casting the literals to shorts" - Should have worked too. - I second @MuratK. in that your code is probably not complete enough to convey the actual problem.

Comment: Perhaps it's related to JDK version or something else and not related to Android Studio. Check JDK version which is used in AS and Eclipse. All works fine in Android Studio 2.1.1 and JDK 7 without any manual casting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing the if with:

```
if ((fileVerMaj.value.comapreTo(new Short((short) 1)) > 0 || ( fileVerMaj.value.compareTo(new Short((short) 1)) == 0 && fileVerMin.value.compareTo(new Short((short) 24)) >= 0) ))
```

The compareTo method returns a negative value if the object called upon is less than the parameter, 0 if they are equal and a positive value if its greater than the parameter. All that said this comparison is a bit overkill for what it does. Can you explain why you need to use Short values instead of primitive shorts or even ints?

Comment: I'm using these variables to store data read from a file header. The data happens to be 16-bits. Changing the code to read that data into integers would be a rather involved process.